# How to Write a Data Validation Formula for an Active field needing a start date but no end date

Tags: validation-rule

My instructions have three conditions (only one of them is stumping me "no end date"):

- if a field status is "active", you must have a start date and no end date
- if it is "previous" it needs an end date.

I was able to create this formula not noticing that I needed a "no end date" requirement attached to my active field, so I added a NOT (ISBLANK)

I tried this formula and it failed, what I am I missing?

```
OR(
    AND(
        ISPICKVAL( Get_the_Worm_subscriber__c , "Active"),
        ISBLANK( GTW_Start_date__c ), 
        NOT(ISBLANK(GTW_End_date_c))
    ),
     AND(
        ISPICKVAL( Get_the_Worm_subscriber__c , "Previous"),
        ISBLANK( GTW_End_date__c )
    ) 
)
```

I didn't think I needed an IF function, but maybe that's what I need? Feel very lost. Hope this all makes sense, I'm new to Salesforce

Comment: I would agree with you that you do not need an `IF()` here. Since validation rules need to result in a true/false, adding an `IF()` would just be more typing. When you say that the validation rule is "failing", do you mean that you're getting an error when you try to save it? Or, does it save just fine but not prevent one (or both) of the scenarios you've laid out?

Comment: without the NOT statement, i couldn't save with an active field and no start date, nor could i save as previous without an end date. with the NOT () I can save for everything. it's like it cancelled everything else out

Answer (score 1):

If the status is Active, it's ok if the record has a start date and no end date, so it  must fail if either the start date is blank or the end date is not blank. [De Morgan's Laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws)

Currently the formula throws an error only if both the start date is blank AND the end date is not blank, so you just need a small change:

```
OR(
    AND(
        ISPICKVAL( Get_the_Worm_subscriber__c , "Active"),
        OR (
            ISBLANK( GTW_Start_date__c ), 
            NOT(ISBLANK(GTW_End_date_c))
        )
    ),
    AND(
        ISPICKVAL( Get_the_Worm_subscriber__c , "Previous"),
        ISBLANK( GTW_End_date__c )
    ) 
)
```

Comment: Hi ! thank you for attaching the link, your's and fred's answer were exactly right! Now I must try and understand how it was right, formulas and validations are short-circuiting my brain.

Answer (score 1):

For a validation rule you need to consider what condition should cause an error. So in your case it's:

- If field status is active, AND start date is blank OR end date is populated
- If field status is previous, end date is not populated

Your formula should be:

```
OR(
    AND(
        ISPICKVAL( Get_the_Worm_subscriber__c , "Active"),
        OR(
            ISBLANK( GTW_Start_date__c ), 
            NOT(ISBLANK(GTW_End_date_c))
        )
    ),
     AND(
        ISPICKVAL( Get_the_Worm_subscriber__c , "Previous"),
        ISBLANK( GTW_End_date__c )
    ) 
)
```

Comment: I do not understand the first point, the OR being put before the second and third logical test for the 1st AND( ), going to try it out though ! thank you!

Comment: It worked !!! yay!! thank you!!

Comment: In the case of "active", you want start date to be populated AND end date to be blank. For a validation rule you need to tell it what you *don't* want it to be. If the start date is blank you want it to error. If the end date is populated you also want it to error. Either of those things should cause it to error, so it's an OR not an AND. If you used AND it would only error if *both* start date was blank and end date was populated.

Comment: ah I see! thank you, that helped me understand it better !